# Which fit-line below is better in R

Tags: r, regression

Please take a look at the below code:
temperature.txt:

| time | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 82 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 3 | 50 |
| 4 | 40 |
| 5 | 32 |
| 6 | 28 |
| 7 | 20 |

```
data <- read.table(file = "temperature.txt", header = TRUE)

plot(data$time, data$temperature, xlab="time", ylab="temperature")

abline(lm(data$temperature ~ data$time))
```

Add the regression line.

Here, another fit with the code:

```
b = (length(data$time)*sum(log(data$time + 1)*data$temperature) -  
    sum(data$time + 
    1)*sum(data$temperature))/(length(data$time)*sum(log((data$time + 
    1)^2)) - (sum(log(data$time + 1)))^2)

a = sum(data$temperature)/length(data$time) - 
    b/length(data$time)*sum(data$time)
```

the line should be:

```
y=a+b*log(data$time+1)
```

change to dataframe style

```
add1 <- data.frame(time=c(0:7), temperature=c(y))
```

Now, compare with these two fit line with graph:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

the first fit method

```
plot(data$time, data$temperature, xlab="time", ylab="temperature")

abline(lm(data$temperature ~ data$time))
```

the second fit method

```
plot(add1$time, add1$temperature, xlab="time", ylab="temperature")

abline(lm(add1$temperature ~ add1$time))
```

the graph below:

[image]

Since I am not good at the theorem of some statistics. I would like to know which method is a better fit, as the graph looks similar.

Comment: welcome to CV. The y values are different between the two graphs so the model isn't quite right. From your comments the graph on the right is a fitted model on the data plotted on the left. Are you wanting compare the fit of that model (y=a+b*log(dataStime+1)) to the actual data? If so generate the trendline from your model and overlay on the data. You can assess fit in a few ways such as the residual variation after you subtract the predictions of proposed model from the actual data, often expressed as $R^2$. There are other metrics depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Gotcha!